# Symfony sfValidators: Dynamically setting a value to be required or not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have the following problem:

I have a form where a user can opt to toggle a switch (`Yes`/`No`).

If they select `Yes`, I hide a couple of fields on my template (because they will now automatically be calculated).

The catch is that *now*, a set of different fields are required to not be empty for the successful submission.

The first fields need not be optional after the switch is clicked (since they are merely hidden but still submitted), but the second set of fields must be non-empty.

Is there a simple way to get this dynamic validation behaviour using Symfony's sfValidator classes, or should I simply hack together a solution using jQuery?

Comment: Sounds like a case that could be solved using the [`Callback` constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Callback.html). However, you'd still need to take care of the `required` attributes in the frontend yourself

Comment: Awesome! That, together with `PostValidator`, solved my validation issue. If you'd like, you can post the above as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect case for the [`Callback` constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Callback.html) that already exists in Symfony. To quote the linked doc:

> The purpose of the Callback constraint is to create completely custom validation rules and to assign any validation errors to specific fields on your object. If you're using validation with forms, this means that you can make these custom errors display next to a specific field, instead of simply at the top of your form.

This solves the backend, you still need to watch out for the `required` attributes of your fields so HTML5 validation can work properly.